# LTspice : using a sqrt(-1) in behavioral model

Tags: ltspice

i would like to simulate an equal circuit of two coupled inductors,
So i need a behavioral voltage with following expressions:

V=j*w*I(R2)

LT spice do not recognize sqrt(-1),

any idea for simulating this circuit? 
[[circuit schematic][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71UKh.png[image]

Comment: Your link didn’t work. Don’t know why. I really-uploaded it. Feel free to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Ltspice does not do complex arithmentic, to make a transformer add a 'K' spice directive specifying the coupling coefficient.

eg: `K L1 L2 0.99`

Comment: i did it befor, i want to check the equivalent circuit, not the original one. because i have a missmatch in my calculation and simulations... and im trying to find it, so its not work that way. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment on @Jasen's answer, use the classical `T` junction-coupled inductors, appropriately valued, and simply perform an `.AC` analysis (if you're interested in a frequency response, as suggested by the `jw` in the OP). The source will be a simple `ac 1`, and the analysis can be for a single-frequency, only. Don't forget about some minimal series resistances, using a voltage source in parallel with an inductor, without any resistance, will cause errors (as expected).